# I can't find the Linux Version of Spotify in my Software center

Tags: software-center, spotify

So, I'm a total new kid to Ubuntu, and I tried to install Spotify using the steps from the Spotify preview build for Linux page. I then did all the steps and saw everything loading correctly but when i came back (i went to eat dinner) my laptop was dead because i stupidly forgot to plug it in to charge. I then searched for the app in my software center, saw nothing and proceeded to download it again. When it was done as well, I also went to look for it in the software and it was still not there.

Finally, I watched a youtube video that explained everything in depth, followed the exact procedures (I'm pretty sure) and then still couldnt find the app. The last two times i attempted to install it, it said it was already installed I think, so where should I like for the file and how should I delete it so I can do it again and learn from my mistake?

Comment: Can you try running `sudo updatedb && locate spotify` and update your question with that information? That would help me get an idea of how to answer your question. Also, when you say you followed the instructions from the site, I assume you mean [from this page?](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/previews/)

Comment: can you just run it from the terminal using `spotify` or `spotify-client`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to install spotify is open your terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and run those commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" &&
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59 &&
sudo apt-get update -qq &&
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

If everything finish with no error then you can be sure that it's installed in your system.

**Now how to find it? Or how to run it?**

Indeed you have to choices: CLI and GUI

**1. For CLI:**  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> again to open terminal then run the command

```
spotify-client
```

**2. For GUI:** you don't have to search for it in Ubuntu software Center(USC) since sure you'll not find it there. USC is just a place to search for applications found in official repositories to find and install. Read this about https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter.

Then now how to find the application. easily all what do you have is to open your dash by clickin on <kbd>super</kbd> key which is called "windows key" also, or with your  mouse click on the dash, then in the search field write `spotify`, this will brings you the application then just <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run

[image]